# Symfony2: get next entity path in show view

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository, entity

I'm beginner in symfony2.

I would like to show a link "previous project" and "next project." in my project view. Like this:[image]
The problem is that I do not know what method to use to get such a result.

I have some ideas like create a function in the entity repository. But I do not know what to do as query.

I did not specifically code to show you. My view maybe:

```
 <aside class="designed-section-2">
        <ul class="realisation-ul-navigation autogrid3">
            <li class="prev-project">
                <a href="{{ prestation['prevRealisationPath'] }}">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/bundles/visualimmersionsite/images/icons/Arrowhead-Left-01-256 (2).png') }}" alt="arrow icon" />
                    <span class="visible-desktop">Réalisation suivante</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="back-to-projects">
                <a href=" {{ path('visual_immersion_site_realisationspage')}}">
                    <img src="{{ asset('/bundles/visualimmersionsite/images/icons/Bullets-256 (1).png') }}" alt="retour news">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="next-project">
                <a href="{{ prestation['nextRealisationPath'] }}">
                    <span class="visible-desktop">Réalisation précédente</span>
                    <img src="{{ asset('/bundles/visualimmersionsite/images/icons/Arrowhead-Right-01-256-hover.png') }}" alt="arrow icon">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
```

I mainly research the correct method for this situation. I have not found anything conclusive on google or stack overflow. I'm a little distraught to this problem that should be current.

if you have some ideas to guide me, I will be very grateful :)

Comment: You can do this in either the controller (should move it to a service once you know exactly how do to it).  In the controller, you will know what page you are on and can query what should be the prev and next project.  I'm assuming that 'project' is an entity and can load it as an ArrayCollection.  From the ArrayCollection you can get the next project and use the key to get the previous project.  You can then pass these values to twig as a string and paste this directly into the link.